# Can i create various scene in diffent class file and switch between them in javafx

Tags: java

Please am new to javafx. the tutorial i watched switched between two scenes that was on the sam class file. I am thinking if i have 10 scenes that will make the code very lenghty. Can i create each scene in a diffrent class file and switch between them in. How?

Comment: Quick idea: `class A extends Scene {...`, `class B extends Scene {...`, `class C { private A a; private B b; public C() { a = new A(); b = new B(); }...`. Then you could do something with `setScene()` to set the scene of your stage.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can, `Scene`s are regular classes after all.

I've created a simple example.
One thing to note: I deliberately did not extend `Scene`, because that is usually unnecessary. You can compose the scenes anywhere you like (in dedicated classes, methods, ...). In this example I used two small factory classes.

```
public class App extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        primaryStage.setScene(SceneAFactory.create(primaryStage));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(App.class, args);
    }
}

public class SceneAFactory
{
    public static Scene create(Stage stage)
    {
        Button button = new Button("Switch to B");
        button.setOnAction(event -> stage.setScene(SceneBFactory.create(stage)));
        return new Scene(new HBox(new Label("Scene A"), button));
    }
}

public class SceneBFactory
{
    public static Scene create(Stage stage)
    {
        Button button = new Button("Switch to A");
        button.setOnAction(event -> stage.setScene(SceneAFactory.create(stage)));
        return new Scene(new HBox(new Label("Scene B"), button));
    }
}
```

Keep in mind though, that depending on the task at hand, replacing just a part of the scene graph might make more sense than replacing the entire scene.